# browser causing multiple button clicks

Tags: browser, click, linkbutton

I have linkbutton that has the onclick event handler. The control is disabled as soon the user clicks but certain users are able to click multiple times.

Not able to reproduce. Could it depend on the browser?

Please help with any ideas

Comment: please provide a code sample without it we are just guessing

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for commenting on this by way of answer field, but I have no other way to do so.

You will need to be a little more specific about the case; could you include the code fragment where the bug seems to occur?